# How to print a specific element from a list using a variable?

Tags: python, list, variables

I've seen a few questions similar to this one, but they don't use a variable and I think that's part of the issue I'm having, not sure though. This is the code:

```
while myNumOfTypes > 0:
    print(allNames[myNumOfTypes], "will be using", allTypes[myNumOfTypes])
    myNumOfTypes = myNumOfTypes - 1
```

I'm getting an out of range error, and I don't really know how to fix it. Also, I know using a for loop would most likely accomplish this task better, but I never really learned for loops. If you can help me using a for loop as well, that'd be great, but not the main concern. allNames and allTypes are both list, allTypes has 18 elements, and allNames has anywhere between 1 and 18, and I only want the results shown to be the same amount that the allNames has, which was earlier determined by myNumOfTypes, which is why in the [] is myNumOfTypes, as the loop would subtract 1 every time and show the next result, which obviously didn't work and why I'm stumped

If more code is needed for clarification, I'd be happy to supply it

*Edit:
After realizing my mistake, thanks to the comments and answers, I realized that I've made another mistake somewhere else in the code where the list allNames is actually a list, with a single list inside with all the names

Comment: Is python your first programming language?

Comment: what is the initial value of `myNumOfTypes`?
Also, what is the length of `allNames` and `allTypes`?

Comment: Indexes go from 0 to length-1. So make sure that `myNumOfTypes` starts at `len(allNames)-1`.

Comment: @Amir The value of myNumOfTypes is determined by the user, but can range from 1 up to 18, the length of allTypes is 18, and the range of allNames is the same as myNumOfTypes

Comment: @Vadim Yes, Python is

Comment: I would recommend giving a direct example of what you want to do here, i.e. give sample values for the variables and tell us exactly what you want it to print. That would make this process easier.

Comment: @Barmar Right! I forgot about that, that should resolve it

Comment: If the user is entering the value of `myNumOfTypes`, you need to make sure it's in the allowed range.

Comment: If both lists have length 18, then the maximum possible initial value of `myNumOfTypes` must be 17. This is because indices start from 0.

Comment: @Vadim for the sake of testing, I've been using 3, so myNumOfTypes and the allNames are both 3, either the value itself or the length of it

Comment: I believe the code has been fixed, thank you

Comment: @TalaatMagdy The loop I use really dosen't matter, I just never learned for loops, but it still works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to print the lists from the end (reverse order) you can do this:

```
for i in range(myNumOfTypes - 1, 0, -1):
    print(allNames[i], "will be using", allTypes[i])
```

But if the regular order is fine, then it can be done like this:

```
for i in range(myNumOfTypes):
    print(allNames[i], "will be using", allTypes[i])
```

I think may be you are getting error because the length of lists is equal to `myNumOfTypes`, and hence when you access `allNames[myNumOfTypes]`, this is out of range (lists start from `0` to `len - 1`)

Comment: As my edit remarked, there's another issue I need to resolve but this was part of the problem, thank you